# Using IDManLib in C# with NativeAOT Support

Tags: c#, native-aot

Can anyone help me because I'm currently upgrading my projects to support for NativeAOT.
I'm using IDManLib to send links directly to IDM (Internet Download Manager)

```
using IDManLib;

public static class IDMNew
{
    public static void SendLinks(IdmParam param)
    {
        new IDManLib.CIDMLinkTransmitterClass().SendLinkToIDM(
            bstrUrl: param.Url,
            bstrLocalPath: param.OutputFolder,
            bstrLocalFileName: param.OutputFileName,
            lFlags: param.Flag,
            bstrReferer: null,
            bstrCookies: null,
            bstrData: null,
            bstrUser: null,
            bstrPassword: null
        );
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting this error and I don't know what to do to fix this because I don't understand the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/how-to-create-com-wrappers?redirectedfrom=MSDN

I'm asking maybe somebody can give me the correct implementation as I am not yet good in reading the documentation especially for complex process.

```
Built-in COM has been disabled via a feature switch. See https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink/com for more information.
System.NotSupportedException: Built-in COM has been disabled via a feature switch. See https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink/com for more information.
   at IDMNew.SendLinks(IdmParam param)
```